Anybody know how to make a relay attack device to boost the keyfob frequency?

This is an example of how the thieves steal cars using relay attacks. I want to know and learn how to build or where to buy the device for educational puroses. I am a 17 year old student in CA Bay Area trying to teach myself something new. Please if you have any ideas message me or leave a comment. Thanks!

you already know the answer to your question ... you even provided a diagram that shows it

i don't, i dont know where to get the device or how to make it.

This question is basically just "can you tell me how to commit a crime".

read the title question you wrote ... the answer is yes ... you provided a diagram that shows that criminals know how to make a relay attack device... this site is a question and answer site, not a chat forum ... ask a clear, specific question ... do not write chat style questions

Anyway, why are you asking again ... if you have additional information, then edit your first question ... do not ask the same question again

@s3mi Being rude to people isn't likely to get anyone to want to help you. The reason there's no information on the device is because this is not a device you can just buy at the hardware store--this is a device with, as far as I know, no non-criminal use, and I imagine they aren't even legal to buy or sell in many jurisdictions.

"Educational purposes" is not a large enough fig leaf to convince us to hand hold your way to creating a device specifically designed to break into cars.

ok i didnt mean to lash out i was just trying to learn and do something with my life. since you guys like to give out so much advice what should i learn to build instead?

Please try and profit from a spelling checker. Please heed site help on how to ask.

@s3mi There's a bit of a difference between "lashing out" and "hurling slurs at people"....

For learning purposes, any kind of radio relay would be just about as educational as a first project.  Such as AM radio.  Or bluetooth for a mouse.  But keep away from hacking into cars/houses/banks.  It's harder than you think, and you won't get much help.  And you'll end up in jail.

@s3mi if you want to learn about something that will enable you to do a vast amount of things with a relatively easy entry level then look at Arduinos. Just web searching the term Arduino will show you a lot and we can provide specific guidance if desired. Some people with lots of experience look down on these as they see them as being a way to do things without learning what you're doing. This is a risk but they are an excellent entry level tool, low-cost and have massive capability for what you put into them. I can provide a number of links if required if you don't find enough on the web

@Hearth It kinda does sound like a device you can buy at the hardware store, depending on just how awfully bad the original design is. If you know the frequency band then some generic RF amplifier with a directional antenna might work. You can buy all of that from Scamazon or a similar toy store.

@Lundin thank you and thanks to whoever tryed to help, to get into more of the specifics, do you know any links that i can buy a 315 mhz RF amplifier than i can attach an antenna too. I also dont know what type of antenna i would need to choose. Youve already helped a lot but if you know any more, itll help a lot.

@s3mi I'm hesitant to help given the questionable purpose, but like I said you can buy such parts at Amazon or similar. Nothing at Amazon will be of good quality however, so there's no guarantees of any particular range. But I very much doubt that car thieves design their own RF boards...
